# NPPES NPI Registry API only returns one item instead of many

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have stored a few provider NPIs in a list called `provider_npi` and I am using the NPPES API to get other information about these NPIs. Currently the list contains three numbers and when I am doing a request.get and then converting it to a JSON object and printing it, it returns only one result and not information for all the NPI numbers included in the list that I created. The desired result is to get information for all the NPIs included in the list. This is my code and results so far:

```
provider_npi = ['1932123213','1588667133','1376542225']

for element in provider_npi:
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?number={element}&pretty=on&enumeration_type=&taxonomy_description=&first_name=&last_name=&organization_name=&address_purpose=&city=&state=&postal_code=&country_code=&limit=&skip=&version=2.1"
    )
    results_json = r.json()
    
print(results_json)
```

[image: the result]

How do I fix this to return to me information for all the MPIs included in the list.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out,

The issue with my code is that i am overwriting the results_json variable in each iteration of the loop, so only the result from the last iteration was getting stored in results_json. To store the results for each NPI separately, I now decided to use a list to store the results. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
final_results = []
for n in npi_list:
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?number={n}&pretty=on&enumeration_type=&taxonomy_description=&first_name=&last_name=&organization_name=&address_purpose=&city=&state=&postal_code=&country_code=&limit=&skip=&version=2.1"
    )
    results = r.json()
    final_results.append(results)
print(final_results)
```

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not a screenshot.